# node.js not running python script after launch

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to make a node.js server that can execute python scripts. Here is the code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/html/index.html`);
})

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
 console.log(`App is listening on port ${listener.address().port}`);
});

app.post("/readPython", (request, response) => {
 var dataToSend;
 const python = spawn('python', ['python/cookie.py'], "Kevin");

 python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  dataToSend = data.toString();
});

 python.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

 python.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}, ${dataToSend}`);
  response.sendFile(`${__dirname}/html/result.html`);
});
});
```

but whenever I type in `node index.js` it starts the server but does nothing else. Any reason why? I am kind of new to node.js

Answer (score 0):

First step to solve this is to bind the `stderr` of the spawned process to the nodeJs' `stdout`.

```
const child = spawn('python', ['python/cookie.py'],{shell:true})
child.stderr.pipe(process.stdout)
```

That way you can get the error message (if any).

In my case, it was not recognizing 'python'. I had to provide the full path where python was installed.

You can get the full installation path in python console by-

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

I also had one more problem. You have to specify the full path of the .py file. If the path contains any spaces, it does not recognizes the file. To avoid that add "'" to your file name argument

```
 const child = spawn('python', ["'"+__dirname+'python/cookie.py'+"'"],{shell:true})
```